# Excel returning all text cells from single row when condition met

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Problem

Currently i have a sheet contianing responses from google form, where a single entry to the form is presented in 1 row. Majority of the responses is a number(1) but there are some that are text responses. In a different sheet i would like to match the row based on timestamp and ID, and then return all the text cells.

Snip of the data format and sheet format

Form1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0W4j.png)

Sheet1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26BeM.png)

Based on the UAS ID and the Date from the sheet1 i would like to find corresponding row in the form1 and return the non-number (so text) cells and their content.

In the situation from the pictures i would like to return in Remarks in Sheet1, the text " No logs" or "Not needed" based on the UAS ID (KCU O) and the timestamp

I've tried vlookup, istext and ifs functions but dont know how to combine all of the conditions

Comment: Are you using Excel or Googlesheets? Googleforms is Googlesheets surely?

Comment: Use `QUERY()` function.